# In Notepad++, How to identify specific line and replace content which includes regex characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

The line which I want to search in all the files are having below pattern:

```
* $Header: <<path and version info>> Exp $
```

E.g.

```
* $Header: /home/cvsd/cvs/root/abc.sp,v 1.1 2016/05/04 10:44:09 abcXyz Exp $
```

The pattern is, line always starts with "* $Header:" and ends with "Exp $"
Since it also contains $, *, and / which are used in building a regular expression I do not know how to deal with it.
Appreciate any help.

Comment: escape them : `\$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^\* \$Header.*\$ *$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/t1X08G/1/).

Comment: That's helpful, a big time saving. Thanks a Ton!